# Sort an array but only the first X number of items in ActionScript?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sorting

I have an integer array and i need to sort the array but only the first 12 numbers.
This is the code i have so far:

```
cantidad_bolillas_array = Bolillas_Array.length;
if(cantidad_bolillas_array > 12) {
    array1 = Bolillas_Array.slice(0, 12);
    array2 = Bolillas_Array.slice(12, cantidad_bolillas_array - 1);
    array1.sort();
    Bolillas_Array = array1.concat(array2);
}else{
    Bolillas_Array.sort();
}
```

but this is not working for me. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to make a few changes, please see comments in updated code sample:

```
var cantidad_bolillas_array:Number = Bolillas_Array.length;
if(cantidad_bolillas_array > 12) {
    var array1:Array = Bolillas_Array.slice(0, 12);
    // when you use slice, remember that the endIndex is exclusive, not inclusive
    // that means you use "last index + 1" to get all the elements in the array
    var array2:Array = Bolillas_Array.slice(12, cantidad_bolillas_array);
    // make sure you sort numerically, otherwise you'll see stuff like 
    // "1, 11, 111, 2, 22, 222" etc
    array1.sort(Array.NUMERIC); 
    Bolillas_Array = array1.concat(array2);
}else{
    // once again, make sure to sort numerically
    Bolillas_Array.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
}
```

Comment: Is not working for me... i dont know why because the logic is correct. My array contains strings like this `["02", "03",....., "01"]` and this code sorts all the elements (i want the "01" to not be sorted)

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, I just tried it with the array `["02", "03", "07", "08", "06", "09", "04", "06", "07", "03", "05", "03", "01"]` and it spit out `02,03,03,03,04,05,06,06,07,07,08,09,01`. Maybe you should post the exact array you are attempting to sort.